# Devise with rails 3 and remote => true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a problem using devise with an AJAX login. I'm using the `:remote => true` option and the jQuery version of the javascript helpers (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).
Ehen the user enters the correct informations, my create.js.erb inside the sessions view is rendered. This is ok, 'cause i can redirect my user using JS in this file. But when an error occurs, e.g. the user enters false information, only the flash messages are in the response with an error code `401 - Unauthorized`. So, no view or create.js.erb or sth else is rendered.
But I want to handle this message, by displaying it on the side, so that the users gets some feedback, whats wrong.

I also tried to implement my own custom controller with `respond_to :js`, and playing with the `:recall` method of the warden authentication. But it doesn't work.

Does anybody know some best practices to solve this problem? Or should I avoid this helper methods and just use pure jQuery for the ajax calls?

thx,
tux

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the jQuery event "ajax:error" in rails 3.  Just bind the event to your form.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#new_model").bind("ajax:error", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert("something went wrong");
  });
});
```

Take a look at this [blog post](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) for more details on what events are available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me, but I have to replace the ajax:failure with a ajax:error

Comment: I updated my answer incase other people don't read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version

```
<script>
  $(document).ajaxError(function(e, XHR, options){
    if (XHR.status == 401){
      window.location.replace("<%= new_user_session_path %>");
    }
  });
</script>
```

It automatically redirects the user to the login page and works for all elements on the page.