# How can I elegantly handle devise's 401 status in AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, devise

With **devise** one uses `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to restrict access to authenticated users only.

When an *unauthenticated* user tries to visit a restricted page anyways, devise automatically causes a redirect to the **sign in** page.

So trying to open http://localhost:3000/users/edit will result in a redirect to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.

Now, if I define the link http://localhost:3000/users/edit as `:remote => true`, devise will only issue a **401 status code** via JS.

How can I elegantly cope with that situation and display the login dialog in **an overlay** OR **redirect as the non-remote variant** would do it?

*Does devise offer a default strategy for that situation which I'd simply need to activate?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the solution I chose for now (in CoffeeScript syntax):

```
$ ->
  $("a").bind "ajax:error", (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) ->
    if jqXHR.status == 401 # thrownError is 'Unauthorized'
      window.location.replace('/users/sign_in')
```

However this (on it's own) just forgets about the page the user wanted to visit initially, which confines usability.

Additional (controller) logic is required for more elegant handling.

**UPDATE: correct redirect**

Within the function, `this` holds the initial URL the user intended to go to.

By calling `window.location.replace(this)` (*instead of explicitly redirecting to the sign in page*), the app will try to redirect the user to the initially intended destination.

Although still impossible (unauthorized), this will now be a GET call (instead of JS/AJAX). Therefore **Devise** is able to kick in and redirect the user to the sign in page.

From there on, Devise operates as usual, forwarding the user to the originally intended URL after successful sign in.

Comment: Use this instead `window.location.replace('/auth/login?return_to=' + window.location.pathname);`

Answer (score 16):

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings) {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
           $('.selector').html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me - I put it in a .js file that gets called on every page where I have ajax submissions, but I replaced the $('.selector').html(xhr.responseText);} with location.reload(); and this kicks Devise into life, redirects to the normal sign-in page & after sign-in brings you back again

Answer (score 2):

A version mixing event binding with `location.reload()`:

```
$(function($) {
  $("#new-user")
    .bind("ajax:error", function(event, xhr, status, error) {
      if (xhr.status == 401) {  // probable Devise timeout
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        location.reload();      // reload whole page so Devise will redirect to signin
      }
    });
});
```

Testing with Devise 3.1.1, this does correctly set `session["user_return_to"]`, so the user returns to the page after signing in again ().

I added the `alert` as a simple way to address the inelegant message issue discussed here:  [Session Timeout Message in RoR using Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19647614)

Comment: I see how this may serve as a workaround to problems regarding timeouts. However, if the sign in form is on a different page, this code seems to fail to redirect to it.

Comment: Do you mean the signin form is on a different page from the standard page? I haven't tried that. Does `rake routes | grep signin` return anything for you? Mine goes to `devise/sessions#new`, which I think is the default (though I have it defined explicitly for other reasons). All this code does is reload the base page, which should force Devise to "**redirect as the non-remote variant** would do it."

Comment: The thing is, if the user "currently" finds himself on a page that he **is** allowed to access unauthenticated, but clicks a link to a page that **does need** him to be authenticated, the proposed solution just reloads the current, already accessible **(!)** page. The intention stays invisible to Devise and session#new (or the like) is untouched. In order to cover both cases, you should redirect to the intended page. See `location.replace` in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, your case is more complex than I originally understood. My app requires authentication for every page, so using the standard Devise flow from the base page works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my copy-past-hapy(tm) solution in CoffeScript. It redirects all 401 to login page.

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers } %>

$(document).ajaxError (_, xhr)->
  window.location = '<%= new_user_session_path %>' if xhr.status == 401
```

and in Javascript:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers } %>

$(document).ajaxError( function(event, xhr){
  if (xhr.status == 401) {
    window.location = '<%= new_user_session_path %>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Rails 5.1 and the new rails-ujs, all custom events return only one parameter: `event`. In this parameter, there is an additional attribute `detail` which contains an array of extra parameters. The parameters `data`, `status`, `xhr` have been bundled into `event.detail`. So handling the 401 error in ajax with the `ajax:error` event becomes:

```
document.body.addEventListener('ajax:error', function(event) {
  var detail = event.detail;
  var response = detail[0], status = detail[1], xhr = detail[2];
  if (xhr.status == 401) {
    // handle error
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .live on the "ajax:error" event binding if you are doing ":remote => true".

```
$('#member_invite, #new_user')
        .live("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
          $.colorbox.close();
        })
        .live("ajax:error", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
          alert("got an error");
        });
```

where the "#new_user" would be the form ID value.

Note that a more elegant way if you already have an overlay or dialog is simply to insert a message, so instead of alert():

```
$('.messages').html('Invalid email or password');
```

and in your signin form you just do a

```
<div class="messages"></div>
```

Or you could even just replace the title of the form, what ever your needs are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think you understood that I am at the login page in the example. However the question is about trying to access a restricted area while unauthenticated. Note that `.live()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()` in jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to see if there is an elegant way to do that too!

Until then, here's how I've handled it.

In your edit.js.erb view file, you can put the following the following code:

```
<% case response.status
  when 200
%>
  //do what you need to do
<% when 401 %>
  //handle the 401 case, for example by redirecting to root or something
  window.location.href('/');
<% else %>
  //catch all
  alert('We\'ve had a problem, please close this, refresh the page and try again');
<% end %>
```

It will look at the status code of the response and redirect to the sign in page if it is 401.

I wonder if there is not a way to handle this directly at controller level.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It is similar to my current approach which I got from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460150/devise-with-rails-3-and-remote-true --- however there is apparently no erb support in that case, which makes it impossible to make a render or even just a DRY redirect to `new_user_session_path` or sth similar.