# Authenticate user, redirect with XHR request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am looking at [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-online-store-rails/) to help me with setting up a "Add to Cart" feature within my application.

Within the guide the author only allows a user to add to the basket if they are signed in (which also means the button is not visible until this point), however I don't want to be restricted by this, so the "Add to Cart" would always be visible, but when clicking if you are not logged in then you would be redirected to the login/signup page.

Within the controller we are using the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` which by default will redirect back to the page you came from once you have signed up/signed in (or so I believe, please advise if this is incorrect).

The issue I have is achieving this with an XHR request. This is the setup so far

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
    cart_ids = $redis.smembers current_user_cart
    @cart_images = Image.find(cart_ids)
  end

  def add
    $redis.sadd current_user_cart, params[:image_id]
    render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
  end

  def remove
    $redis.srem current_user_cart, params[:image_id]
    render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
  end

  private

  def current_user_cart
    "cart#{current_user.id}"
  end
end
```

View

```
<%=link_to "", data: { target: @cart_action, addUrl: add_to_cart_path(@image), removeUrl: remove_from_cart_path(@image) } do %>
  <i class="di-shopping-cart-up"></i>
  <span><%= @cart_action %></span> Cart
<% end %>
```

CoffeeScript

```
$(window).load ->
  $('a[data-target]').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $this = $(this)
    if $this.data('target') == 'Add to'
      url = $this.data('addurl')
      new_target = "Remove from"
   else
    url = $this.data('removeurl')
    new_target = "Add to"
  $.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->
  $('.badge-number').html(data)
  $this.find('span').html(new_target)
  $this.data('target', new_target)
```

What happens at the moment when I click "Add to Cart" is that the request fails with a `401 Unauthorized` in the console with the response `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

How can I approach this?

Comment: In your terminal, does it log something like WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity  ?

Comment: no, cannot see anything like that

Comment: And you are already logged in ?

Comment: I am not logged in, i would like to be redirected if I am not logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch the 401 in your ajax response and then redirect like this:

```
  $(document).on "ajaxError", (event, request, settings) ->
    if request.status == 401
      window.location.href = '/'
```

Comment: thanks, excuse my further question but twhat you have provided would come after `$.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->` not quite sure at this stage how to integrate this into the current coffeescript

Comment: You can just bind 'ajaxError' like I did in the example, or add `succes: (data) ->` and `error: (data) ->` to your own calls

Comment: ah i see, ok so that does work, but now I've lost the behavior of `authenticated_user` that would redirect you back to the page i came from once logged in. Is this something that can be achieved? thank you

Comment: No, what i mean is that `authenticated_user` will redirect you to a login page for example, once you have completed login you normally get redirected back to where you came from, with this implementation (which i do thank you for) i just get taken back to the home page, doesnt matter if i change `window.location.href`... think i need to look at solutions within the controller

Comment: i found this which i believe will assist greatly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124832/how-can-i-elegantly-handle-devises-401-status-in-ajax

Comment: Nice, could you please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: ill accept, but could you make a note that it doesnt handle the `authenticate_user` `session["user_return_to"]`, not to confuse people who read this thinking that this is the complete answer. thank you

Comment: If you want to handle `session["user_return_to"]`, why not just put this value on a data attribute in your views and make `window.location.href = $("#hidden-div").data('user_return_to')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98820/discussion-between-richlewis-and-laurens).

Comment: wouldnt that just redirect me back to the same page without even getting to my login page ?... just tried it, it does